# Record edited twice if edited column has index

Tags: ms-access, dao

TableA has one column 'fielda' of type Long.

There are three records in the table with values 3,4 and 5 respectively.

After running the code below the values should be 18, 19 and 20.

This is the case if there isn't an index on fielda but if there is then the vaues will be
33, 19 and 20.

One record gets edited twice. Is this a bug in DAO or is this normal behaviour?

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim s1 As String

s1 = "select * from tableA"
Set DB = OpenDatabase(DBAddress)
Set rs = MyDB.OpenRecordset(s1)
If Not rs.BOF Or Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("fielda").Value = rs.Fields("fielda").Value + 15
        rs.Update
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was unable to recreate the behaviour you describe I can offer one possible explanation. As you are stepping through the records you may hit the same record more than once if the Recordset periodically checks for changes that may have been made to the underlying table by other users.

Say your Recordset starts out as

3   4   5

and you update the first record so the table now contains

18   4   5

if the Recordset then tries to "refresh" itself and the index on [fielda] controls the order in which the records appear in the Recordset it could end up being

<strike>3</strike>   4   5   18

and if it continues updating until .EOF the final result could be

<strike>3</strike>   19   20   33

Possible workarounds would be to

- create the Recordset with a SQL statement that includes an ORDER BY clause on *some other field* so the order of the records will not change as you modify them, or
- apply the update via SQL, e.g. `UPDATE tableA SET fielda = fielda + 15`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your second solution worked, the first didn't, the same result occurred. The database is an access97 one so I used dao 3.5.1. For curiousity I switched to dao 3.6 and this also fixed the issue. But an Access 97 database should not be used in conjunction with dao 3.6 as far as I know

Comment: @kjack Thanks for the feedback. I don't support Access 97 any more so I can't really offer any specific advice except "upgrade to a newer version". ;)